# How can I add a white strip with my name below each image in Lightroom or Photoshop?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, watermark

Some photographers add a white strip below their [image](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/0a/c5/58/0ac55804a7fee591a5ce36c2ce8628a8.jpg) with their name. I like the idea, because is less disturbing than a watermark. Is there a way to do this with Lightroom or Photoshop? Or do I need a special software?

Answer (score 10):

**Yes**, you can do this in Photoshop. All you need is to expand the canvas (Image > Canvas size) and then add you logo, name or other decoration into this new space.

Please note that this is extremely easy to remove from the image (just by cropping), so it does not really fulfill the same function as watermark.

Comment: You could also easily create an action for this.

Comment: If your watermark is unobtrusive, it's easy to remove with minimal PS skills anyway. If it is very obtrusive, then it will make your photo kinda suck. It really won't stop anyone from using your photo if they want to. I watermark mine simply as branding, I have no expectations of security from it.

Answer (score 4):

In Lightroom, you'd have to do this via the `Print` module.

Create a template with an `Identity Plate` which contains your name/signature/logo and print your photos using this template to jpg (or whatever).

(Random YouTube tutorial for this: https://youtu.be/l7LzNNNFqHU)

Answer (score 4):

To add to the answer about Lightroom you can add watermark also in development module. The only remark is watermark will be inside the photo!

1. In menu: Edit->Edit Watermarks... Select text and/or image which
   will be your watermark. Save it as preset.
   [image: Watermark preset]
2. In Develop module in Export select Watermarking and preset you
   create on point 1
   [image: Export dialog]

Edit 1: The same preset work in Print module. Unfortunately in version 6 (perpetual license) in Edit->Edit Watermarks... set **Inset** vertical to negative value have no effect (no extend of canvas, no watermark) in Develop and Print module. And I am wondering why is possible to define negative values at all